# Jump to the end of body of headline

Tags: org-mode, motion

What is the key combination to jump directly to the end of BODY of a headline in org-mode?

```
* Headline title A from here ▮

text text text
text text text
text text text
text text text
text text text
to HERE▮

* Headline title B
```

Comment: Using `C-e` cursor move to end of the headline title `* Headline title HERE ▮` and not to the end of HEADLINE-BODY:
`...text text text
text text text
to HERE▮`

Comment: Sorry - misread the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a function that does this (someone will correct me if there is), but you can write your own by getting the `:contents-end` property from an org element and going to that buffer location. Something similar to this:

```
(defun my/org-goto-end-of-contents ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((elem (org-element-at-point))
         (end-pos (org-element-property :contents-end elem)))
    (goto-char end-pos)))
```

The important part being `(org-element-property :content-end elem)`, which returns the value you're looking for. (Take a glance these two functions with `C-h f`: `org-element-property` and `org-element-at-point`)

However, if you want this function to respect the empty line and the end of the buffer, you can spice it up by looking for blank lines, headings, etc:

```
(defun my/org-goto-end-of-contents ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((elem (org-element-at-point))
         (end-pos (org-element-property :contents-end elem)))
    (goto-char end-pos)
    (if (and (or (looking-at-p "[[:space:]]*$") 
                 (org-at-heading-p))
             (not (eobp)))
     (left-char 1))))
```

Bind this function to your key of choice and you're good to go.

Comment: There is the built-in function `org-end-of-subtree` which seems to be equivalent to the first command here.

Comment: I knew someone would know of a built-in function. That being said, it's fun to tinker with `org-element-at-point` and its properties. Thanks, @orgtre!

Answer (score 2):

The commands [provided by kozina-adjacent](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75926/334240) go to the end of the current subtree, as does `org-end-of-subtree`. However, if one has a heading with text under it followed by several subheadings, one might just want to go to the end of the text before the first subheading. For this [I wrote](https://github.com/orgtre/org-colviewx/blob/5fbd190907cad44e1a6b533e7ca33ec698019963/org-colviewx.el#L246) the following command (it does as advertised with a universal argument prefix, but does other things too, and could be further improved):

```lisp
(defun org-colviewx-beginning-of-contents (&optional arg)
  "Go to first non-whitespace character of entry content.
Skips meta-data. When the entry content is only meta-data and
whitespace, go to the first subheading; but if there is no
subheading go to the end of of the last non-meta-data line of
entry, inserting it if necessary.

With a `\\[universal-argument]' prefix argument go to last \
non-whitespace
character instead. With a `\\[universal-argument] \
\\[universal-argument]' prefix argument go to
last non-whitespace character in subtree."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((initial-level (org-current-level)))
    (org-end-of-meta-data t)
    (if (and (org-at-heading-p)
             (= initial-level (org-current-level)))
        (progn (backward-char)
               (when (save-excursion
                       (backward-char)
                       (looking-at-p "[^ \n\t]"))
                 (newline)))
      (cond
       ((equal arg '(4))
        (if (re-search-forward "[ \n\t]*\n\\*" nil t)
            (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
          (org-end-of-subtree)
          (re-search-backward "[^ \n\t]")
          (goto-char (match-end 0))))
       ((equal arg '(16))
        (org-end-of-subtree t)
        (re-search-backward "[^ \n\t]")
        (goto-char (match-end 0)))))
    (when (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
      (org-fold-show-context))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for just what the `org-end-of-subtree` function does!

Comment: If one of these answers has answered your question satisfactorily, please [accept it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).